# WCF Json Service Parameters are Null

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, null

I've found some good threads on this but none that solve my issue yet. If anyone has any ideas I'm open to suggestions! Thank you.

I'm using WCF to build a REST JSON service that will accept a Member object and insert it into my database. However, the parameters all seem to be null when sent to my service using Fiddler. If I sent the values in my service code they get inserted correctly to the database.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "PutMember")]
int PutMember(Member member1);
```

My fiddler call is a POST to `http://127.0.0.1:81/Service1.svc/PutMember` with this header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: application/json
```

And body:

```
{"member1":
[{
"first_name":"shaw",
"last_name":"levin",
"gender":0,
"Grad_Year":2015,
"personality":3,
"campus":1,
"social":0,
"cleaning":1,
"diet":1,
"religious":3,
"roomamate_prefs":"Hello",
"hs_engagement":"World"
}]}
```

The data contract looks like this:

```
[DataMember]
public int Primary_ID
{
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string First_Name
{
    get { return _first; }
    set { _first = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an array instead of single object. Try to send:

```
{"member1":
{
"first_name":"shaw",
"last_name":"levin",
"gender":0,
"Grad_Year":2015,
"personality":3,
"campus":1,
"social":0,
"cleaning":1,
"diet":1,
"religious":3,
"roomamate_prefs":"Hello",
"hs_engagement":"World"
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped fix my problem but I also needed to do the fix suggested by Markus (case sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

The case of the JSON properties and the C# properties must match, or you must specify another case in the attribute.

```
[DataMember]
public string first_name { get; set; }
```

or

```
[DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
public string First_Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped fix my problem but I also needed to do the fix suggested by Konrad (case sensitive).